Is it possible to hide TwinCAT3 EventLogger messages from the Error List window in Visual Studio?
I have a project with a nicly working setup using the TwinCAT3 EventLogger. I use the FB_TcAlarm a lot to raise/clear and acknowledge alarms. All these alarms and there states show-up on the TcHmiEventGrid and the Logged Events window in Visual Studio.
What I don't like however, the alarms also show up in the Error List window in Visual Studio. Here are also the compile errors/warnings reported.
I want to reserve the Error List window for compile errors and such. So I don't want the TC event logger alarms to show here. I will inspect them via the other available means.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you for any help.

You can prevent the event logger messages from showing up in the error list by selecting Tools > Options > TwinCAT XAE Environment > EventLogger and then set Output as Task Item to False.


This seems to be the official way. I will test it tomorrow. Thank you.

This works! Please note, a restart of Visual Studio (Shell) is required for changes to this setting to take effect.

have you tried to use the filter from the error list to filter out the events?
Error list filter
Also if your goal is just to see compile errors and warnings, you can just compile without connecting to the target device, that way no events will display. And once compile errors and warnings are checked out, you can activate code on device and then only focus on event logger window from that point.

Thanks! I will give the filters a try. During development you are right, but at some point when I start testing, I'm connected to a target device, but also make changes to fix/tune things and then it is annoying I cannot see the compiler errors easily between all the other messages.

Thanks! This works, the project is blank in such a case and I can filter that out. The only concern I have is now I could also miss other messages which have project as blank. Still this would do if no other way exists. I wait for a bit with accepting the answer, maybe someone else has an idea, and otherwise this is it. Thank you for sure!
